# How to prove that a predicate is decidable?

Tags: predicate-logic

Prove the following predicates are decidable knowing that $A$ and $B$ are decidable predicates:
$$\lnot A$$
$$A \lor B$$

I am supposed to prove this by writing a program or using some other way that a predicate is decidable but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: ... do you know how to program in the first place?

Comment: This seems pretty obvious to me.  If you can decide whether or not $A$ is true, then you certainly can determine whether or not $\neg A$ is true (just return the opposite decision you got from deciding $A$).  Then the same for $A \vee B$.  Just decide $A$ and $B$ and if either are true, then you have decided $A \vee B$ is true and if both are false, then you have decided that $A \vee B$ is false.

Comment: @Jared True, but I'm guessing the OP is supposed to write a formal proof, which requires a particular formalization of "algorithm" (i.e., some programming language or recursive functions or whatever)

Comment: Yeah, I know how to program, but as fgp said, I need to write a formal proof and I am not sure how o write it. The problem too simple that I am finding it very difficult to prove. Also, I think I should use the while language if I wanted to write a program

Answer (score 0):

You have to use at least an "abstract" model of algorithm.

Assume that you have a "machine" - call it $M_A$ - which, receiving as input one object $x$ in your domain of discourse in turn, after a finite amount of time stops and gives you the answer **YES** if $A$ holds for that object $x$, and **NO** if $A$ does not hold for $x$.

Now, having $M_A$, we can easily build up the $M_{\lnot A}$ "machine" : "run" the $M_A$ machine with input $x$ and , when it stops and ouput **YES**, then "add" a new instruction which translate the output into **NO** (and vice versa). This is the new "machine" $M_{\lnot A}$.